# Background infinite loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, loops, asynchronous

Using python 3.8.5, i've try to create a class object which have a inside infinite loop which will update a value that i can have to read later... Unfortunaly, my knowledge on this field are a little poor.

The aims of this trial is to dissociate an app which has a state from the gui i've made...

Here is one not working trial i've made.

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep


class value_holder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
        asyncio.create_task(self.infinite_loop())
    
    async def infinite_loop(self):
        while True:
            self.value += 1 
            sleep(3)


v = value_holder()

while True:
    print(v.value)
    sleep(1)
```

I'm actually clueless so if someone have any clue or keyword for helping me in this search of solution, i will be very thankful

Best regards

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The main question is : Using the sample code i gave, how can i made a class nest his own process, without blocking the execution of the rest of the program ?

Moreover, does this kind of problematic have some kind of terminology? for facilitate my research with good keyword

Comment: `dissociate an app which has a state from the gui i've made.` - Run the app in a separate process and communicate via queues or pipes or sockets?

Comment: asyncio is an asynchronous process - It sounds like you want concurrent execution [https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work with a timer instead :

```
import threading
from time import sleep

class value_holder:
    value = 0
    timer = None
    delay = 1

    def __init__(self, delay):
        self.value = 0
        self.delay = delay

    def run(self):
        self.value += 1
        print(self.value)
        if self.timer != None: self.start()

    def start(self):
        self.timer = threading.Timer(self.delay, self.run) 
        self.timer.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.timer.cancel()

v = value_holder(3.0)
v.start()
sleep(9) #==> 1, 2, 3
v.stop()
print("Stopped")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I modify a little for validate the answer by putting the print value outside the class and it's seem that the value could be read in real time, so it's work.